# How to add scroll to child of flex item?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, overflow

With a flex container with a fixed height, I can make a flex item scrollable by setting `overflow: auto`, like so:

```css
page {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  height: 200px;
}
left-panel {
  flex: 1;
  display: block;
  background: lightblue;
}
//main {flex: 5; display: block;}
header {
  background: turquoise;
  display: block
}
//main-content-wrapper {flex: 4; display:flex; flex-direction: column}
right-panel {
  flex: 1;
  overflow: auto;
}
content-panel {
  background: pink;
  display: block;
}
content {
  height: 1000px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<page>
  <left-panel>left-panel
    <br/>(static)</left-panel>
  <right-panel>
    <header>
      header
      <br/>(static)
    </header>
    <content-panel>
      <content>
        content
        <br/>(scrolls)
      </content>
    </content-panel>
  </right-panel>
</page>
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aalasso/p8m5e21z/2/)

But I would like to make a child of the flex item scroll instead.

I would think that setting `height: 100%` on the flex item and `overflow: auto` on the child element I want to scroll would work, but it does not:

```css
page {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  height: 200px;
}
left-panel {
  flex: 1;
  display: block;
  background: lightblue;
}
//main {flex: 5; display: block;}
header {
  background: turquoise;
  display: block
}
//main-content-wrapper {flex: 4; display:flex; flex-direction: column}
right-panel {
  flex: 1;
  height: 100%;
}
content-panel {
  background: pink;
  display: block;
  overflow: auto;
}
content {
  height: 1000px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<page>
  <left-panel>left-panel
    <br/>(static)</left-panel>
  <right-panel>
    <header>
      header
      <br/>(static)
    </header>
    <content-panel>
      <content>content
        <br/>(scrolls)</content>
    </content-panel>
  </right-panel>
</page>
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aalasso/p8m5e21z/3/)

How can I make this work?

And why doesn't the second fiddle work?

*Added OP comments:*

- I can see there are several related questions, but the ones I found are either not directly applicable, or mention workarounds to bugs that may have been fixed since.
- I would like to avoid using explicit height calculations to reduce coupling of components.
- I could convert the right-panel into a nested flexbox with `flex-direction: column`, but I was hoping to avoid that.
- In case a flat structure (like in the second fiddle) is not possible without an explicit height calculation, it would be nice with an explanation of why. Could it be considered a bug with flexbox or am I misunderstanding something fundamental about css?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're applying `overflow: auto` to an element so it can launch a vertical scrollbar, then also give it a height limitation.

In this case, you just need to add `height: 100%` to the element you want to make scrollable.

```
content-panel {
  background: pink;
  display: block;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100%; /* NEW */
}
```

Of course, you'll need to adjust the actual percentage value to subtract the height of the header. Maybe something like this:

```
height: calc(100% - 80px)
```

***OR, perhaps a better approach*** (and consistent with your added comments rejecting fixed heights), just make `right-panel` a column-direction flex container:

```css
page {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  height: 200px;
}
left-panel {
  flex: 1;
  display: block;
  background: lightblue;
}
header {
  background: turquoise;
  display: block
}
right-panel {
  flex: 1;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;          /* NEW */
  flex-direction: column; /* NEW */
}
content-panel {
  background: pink;
  overflow: auto;
}
content {
  height: 1000px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<page>
  <left-panel>left-panel
    <br/> (static)</left-panel>
  <right-panel>
    <header>
      header
      <br/>(static)
    </header>
    <content-panel>
      <content>content
        <br/>(scrolls)</content>
    </content-panel>
  </right-panel>
</page>
```

---

#### EDIT (based on revised question)

With regard to the `overflow` property:

> The `overflow` property specifies whether to clip content, render
>   scrollbars or just display content when it overflows its block level
>   container.
>
> In order for the `overflow` property to have an effect, the block
>   level container must either have a bounding height (`height` or
>   `max-height`) or have `white-space` set to `nowrap`.
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I did try both of these approaches but thought there should be a cleaner way. @1) Avoiding the explicit height calculation of the child is my main motivation for using flexbox. @2) This works, but seems somewhat clunky, for something I thought would be easy.

Comment: The second method doesn't require fixed heights. Just uses flex properties.

Comment: True. I was trying to address that with "@2)" in my previous comment.

Comment: Is it clear now, or you're still looking for a simpler solution?

Comment: It was clear the whole time. But yes, I would prefer a cleaner solution if it exists.

Comment: Making the right panel a flex container seems very clean and simple to me. It also gives you great flexibility by allowing you to use flex properties. I can't think of anything easier, simpler or more natural. Flex layout is designed for this sort of thing.

Comment: I suppose the reason I find it less than optimal is because I don't understand _why_ my second fiddle does not work – if it did, I would consider that cleaner. Could it be considered a bug with the flexbox implementation, or am I missing something in how css works?

Comment: @AdamAL, the second fiddle doesn't work for reasons described in my answer: Your element with `overflow: auto` doesn't have a defined height. And no, this is not a bug with flexbox. In fact, the child elements of `right-panel` aren't even participating in flex layout (which exists only between parent and child). The child elements of `right-panel` exist in a standard block formatting context.

Comment: @Michael_B; I see. It seems I have some catching up to do on the box-model. For the same reason, I thought the second fiddle would work, I would have thought this simpler, flexbox-free, fiddle would have capped the child ellement and allowed it to scroll: https://jsfiddle.net/aalasso/p8m5e21z/5/

Comment: In looking at your fiddle, keep this in mind: The `overflow` property targets the *content* of a block level container. You've applied `overflow: auto` to the child. But the child has no overflowing content. You need to put the `overflow` on the parent, because it is a block level container and its content is the child.

Comment: this only works for me when `page` has a constrained height (i.e. 200px). In many applications, `height: 100vh` is desired and this does not result in scroll when using `100vh`.

Answer (score 1):

Make your `right-panel` a column `flexbox` and add `flex:1` to `content-panel` - see demo below:

```css
page {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  height: 200px;
}
left-panel {
  flex: 1;
  display:block;
  background: lightblue;
}
header {
  background: turquoise;
  display:block;
}
right-panel {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;/*Added this*/
  flex-direction: column;/*Added this*/
  height: 100%;
}
content-panel {
  background: pink;
  display:block;
  overflow: auto;
  flex:1; /*Added this*/
}
content {
  display: block;
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<page>
  <left-panel>left-panel
    <br/>(static)</left-panel>
  <right-panel>
    <header>
      header
      <br/>(static)
    </header>
    <content-panel>
      <content>
        content
        <br/>(scrolls)
        <br/>more content here
        <br/>more content here
        <br/>more content here
        <br/>more content here
        <br/>more content here
        <br/>more content here
        <br/>more content here
        <br/>more content here
        <br/>more content here
      </content>
    </content-panel>
  </right-panel>
</page>
```

Answer (score 0):

your `content-panel` already has `height 1000px` and your `content` has `overflow:auto`. The only thing you missed is you did not specify the `content-panel` `height`. `content-panel height` must < `content height` in order for it to display scroll bar

```
<content-panel>
    <content>
      content
      </br>(scrolls)
    </content>
</content>
```

Comment: I think the OP wanted to use `flex: 1` to achive the desired height for `content-panel` rather than "hard coding" a height.